# Gtags to index global variables

Tags: variables, tags, gnu, gnu-global

I want gnu global to index global variables of the project.
Is that possible (without having to get into the source of gnu global)?

Comment: I modified gnu global to support part of global var index. See https://github.com/lianhaidong/global/tree/kernel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is not implemented yet. You can see it's in the [plan](http://www.gnu.org/software/global/plans.html) of gnu global.

> Treat variable definitions as a definition tag (GTAGS).